# Could not load action bar icon: res://back

Tags: nativescript

In preview mode i can't view the action bar icon but if I build the project in android I can see them.
In the console I have this:

```
LOG from device OnePlus X: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
LOG from device OnePlus X: Error: Could not load action bar icon: res://back
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by preview mode you mean the nativescript preview application on your phone then you get the error because your resource is missing, as in the preview you don't carry your App_Resources folder on the device

Comment: This should definitely be written somewhere in the docs, I spent almost a day trying to understand why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Copy menu_black.png image to all resolution folders, since menu_black.png is not available for resolution of your respective emulator it is not visible. In tutorial they only have shown to add this image for **mdpi and xdpi** but that's not sufficient please add this image in all other available resource folders.

**I have attached an image which shows the reply from Udemy tutor itself**
[image]